# django - Can't login after creating user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't login after create user. Here's my code:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.pop('username')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        return User.objects.create_user(username, password, **validated_data)
```

My api:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

any help is appreciated.
Updated: Here's my test case

```
class UserAPITestCase(APITestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient()

    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='anhnguyen',
        password=PASSWORD,
    )
    self.user.save()

def test_create_user(self):
    data = {
        'username': 'khoavo',
        'password': PASSWORD,
    }

    user = self.client.post(URL, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(user.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    url = reverse(URL1, args=[2])
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    login = self.client.login(username='khoavo', password=PASSWORD)
    self.assertTrue(login)
```

The test case failed at login statement after creating a user

Comment: I tried to debug in Serializer. After the UserSerializer validate the input data, it can create an instance by create method. But somehow that instance can't not login in the my test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method takes `email` as its second argument. You could fix the problem by changing `password` to a keyword argument:

```
return User.objects.create_user(username, password=password, **validated_data)
```

Comment: email, password and other fields are just optional parameter. You can create an instance of User by just providing username. So ...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Yes, you can create a user with just a username, but then you won't be able to log in. Your current code `User.objects.create_user(username, password, **validated_data)` is equivalent to `User.objects.create_user(username, email=password, **validated_data)`. That's why you should change it to `password=password`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is sending all with `**`:

```
...
def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
...
```

It would solve your issue

Comment: I tested and this should work. If `validated_data` is a dictionary, this should work as passing kwargs to `create_user ()`. If it's not working, the problem should be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`self.client.login()` is used for testing APIs that use session authentication. Make sure that you are using session authentication.

If you are using token based authentication instead, you should do like this:

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the method create_user, password will be hashed. So we don't need to hash at that step.

Comment: @user3857032 you are right. Sorry. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The problem is not about kind of authentication coz I had done like that before. As the third comment, I did a mistake in term of parameter of create method in serializer. btw thank you